# TSQL - char changing to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, char

I need the variable @end_period be character e.g. 01 and not 1
What is wrong with the following code?

```
DECLARE @start_year AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @end_year AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @start_period AS CHAR(2)
DECLARE @end_period AS CHAR(2)
DECLARE @start_date as datetime
DECLARE @end_date as datetime

SET @start_year = '2014'
SET @end_year = '2014'
SET @start_period = '07'
SET @end_period = '08'

SET @end_year = CASE WHEN @end_period ='12' THEN @end_year + 1 ELSE @end_year END
SET @end_period = CASE WHEN @end_period ='12' THEN '01' ELSE @end_period + 1 END


select @end_year
select @end_period
```

Comment: Why don't you use `dateadd` and `datepart ` instead all these stuff. you can transfer date formatted string into date first.

Answer (score 2):

There's something weird about using CHAR.  I don't know why but when I do this, I get your desired results:

```
DECLARE @start_year AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @end_year AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @start_period AS CHAR(2)
DECLARE @end_period AS CHAR(2)
DECLARE @start_date as datetime
DECLARE @end_date as datetime

SET @start_year = '2014'
SET @end_year = '2014'
SET @start_period = '07'
SET @end_period = '08'

SET @end_year = CASE WHEN @end_period ='12' THEN @end_year + 1 ELSE @end_year END
SET @end_period = CASE WHEN @end_period ='12' THEN '01' ELSE RIGHT('0'+CAST((@end_period + 1) AS varchar(2)) ,2) END


select @end_year
select @end_period
```

However when I change this:  `CAST((@end_period + 1) AS varchar(2))`

To this:  `CAST((@end_period + 1) AS char(2))`

I just get a '9' instead of '09'.   Weird.  I don't know why.

EDIT:  MYSTERY SOLVED.

I don't know why I didn't think of this right away.  Actually, I do.  It's only 9 am.

The '9' that you are seeing as a result is actually '9 '  (9 with a blank space after it) because char(2) has to have 2 characters in it.  So doing RIGHT('0'+'9 ') is of course going to return '9 '.  You could use RTRIM() or REPLACE() to get rid of the space while preceding it with a zero if you want, or you can just use the varchar cast I illustrated above.

Comment: I explained the reason for the *weird* conversions in my post. This has nothing to do with the casts, they are done implicitly anyway.

Comment: Ndech, have you actually executed your code?   Because I just did, and I got '9' as a result.  Not the desired '09'.

Comment: The first part of my code explain the reason why it works that way and why is not "weird". The second part of my code provide a solution, the same as yours.

Comment: You aren't carefully reading my answer.  The thing you explained about +1 implicitly creating an integer isn't the thing that I said was weird.  The thing that seemed weird is that if you don't cast the CHAR as a VARCHAR, then the RIGHT() function appears not to work.  However, in my edited answer above, I figured out why.  It's really not weird, but it can be surprising at first glance.  And you of all people should agree it's surprising since you thought your solution would work.  And no, your solution is not the same as mine.  Mine works and yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you do :

```
@end_period + 1
```

Example :

```
'08'+1
```

The string '08' is converted to the integer 8, one is added, result => 9.
An implicit conversion is then made back to char(2), which is '9'.

The full matrix of possible conversions (implicit or explicit) can be found [on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)

---

To solve your problem, you can then add leading zeroes this way :

```
SET @end_period = CASE WHEN @end_period ='12' THEN '01' ELSE RIGHT('00' + CAST((@end_period + 1) as VARCHAR(2)), 2) END
```

Comment: Your explanation is pretty nice, though there is pretty sure no implicit conversion back happening, the whole thing will be interpreted as int (due to higher datatype precedence and all branches of a case must return the same datatype) - but the code you wrote does not seem to eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SET @end_period = CASE WHEN @end_period = '12' THEN '01' 
                   ELSE CASE WHEN @end_period > 8 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,@end_period + 1) 
                             ELSE '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@end_period + 1) 
                        END 
               END
```